# How do I stop the padding modifier from messing up my dashed lines?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui, shapes

One of the views of my swiftui app require a dash line running through the background. I added this by creating a custom shape called MyLine that creates a path using the following code:

```
var path = Path()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
    
    return path
```

I make it a dashed line using

```
.stroke(style: StrokeStyle(dash: [10]))
```

Finally, I add it to the blackground of my intended view using the background modifier:

```
.background(
        MyLine()
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, dash: [10]))
    )
```

This all works great except for one problem: whenever ANY padding is added to the line the dashes become lopsided as shown below. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Before Padding:
[image: Before Padding]

After Padding
[image: After Padding]

Minimum reproducible example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyLine: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
        
        return path
    }
    
    
}
struct MyLineTest: View{
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            MyLine()
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(dash: [10]))
        }.frame(height: 60)
            .padding() //Remove this line to fix the dashes
    }
}

struct MyLine_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyLineTest()
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

Just paste this code into an empty swift view file.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippets, but could you please add a [mcve] to make it easier for people to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sure, I'll add a MRE

Comment: It is a co sequence of writing 2 lines in the path not only one. The begin of the second line is not always at the middle of dash or dash interval . That is why you have this result.

Comment: Thanks Ptit, If you put that as an answer I can mark it as having solved the problem.